# Ensure event can never have more than one subscriber

Tags: c#, .net, events, .net-core

I want to ensure that the particular event can never have more than one subscriber. In my particular case it does not make sense to have multiple subscribers, and some sneaky problems might occur if it will.

*Side note: Particularly, my handler (subscriber) has to be `async` and I have to `await` it when raising the event. The reason is that this is a network-socket-wrapping class, where I raise the TextReceived event, and I don't want to read any more data from the socket, before the user (subscriber) has finished processing last TextReceived event (because user usually writes some reply to the socket, and multiple in-flight callbacks will cause collision). Maybe this case can better be solved another way (without async events), and I'm trying to solve the wrong problem. If so, how?*

Here is the solution that I've come up with, but I wonder whether it is the only option, or if it can be simplified any further.

This is my code:

```
    private TextReceivedAsyncHandler _textReceivedAsync;

    public event TextReceivedAsyncHandler TextReceivedAsync
    {
        add
        {
            if (_textReceivedAsync != null)
                throw new MultipleSubscribersNotAllowedException(eventName: nameof(TextReceivedAsync));

            _textReceivedAsync = value;
        }
        remove
        {
            _textReceivedAsync = null;
        }
    }
```

Is this the proper shortest way to restrict multiple subscribers, or can you propose more elegant solution? I thought of using public delegate property instead of an event, but that does not solve any problems because delegates are multicast anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure there is anything wrong with your approach; if you want to have more control over it, you can implement the observer pattern yourself (any make it async) or create a callback property instead (less SOLID).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would still suggest to expose delegate itself. Yes, delegates are multicast and it still might reference to multiple methods. However, *semantics* of event assumes possibility of multiple subscribers, and restricting this is very confusing to the users of your code. However, if you expose delegate it's very clear only one "subscriber" is expected. To prevent using `+=` syntax, you can do it like this:

```
private Func<YourEventArgs, Task> _callback;
public Func<YourEventArgs, Task> Callback
{
   set { _callback = value; }
}
```

It's true that user might still pass delegate with multiple methods:

```
Func<YourEventArgs, Task> delegateA = ...;
Func<YourEventArgs, Task> delegateB = ...;
Callback = delegateA + delegateB;
```

But the same is true for your `TextReceivedAsync` event too, and I think that's a problem of subscriber himself.

One more options, if you *really* want to prevent multicast delegates, is:

```
private Func<YourEventArgs, Task> _callback;
public Func<YourEventArgs, Task> Callback
{
    set
    {
        if (value != null && value.GetInvocationList().Length > 1) {
            throw new Exception("...");
        }
        _callback = value;                
     }
 }
```